# Dim volume of iPodMusicPlayer to 50% in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

I know that you can easily [set the volume property of the music player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286744/how-to-change-device-volume-on-ios-not-music-volume), but I want to do it smoothly like Google Maps does when they use the voiceover for navigation instructions.

I was wondering what the best way to do this is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using a repeating NSTimer. Every time the timer fires you lower the volume a bit. When it reaches the target value you invalidate the timer.

Other ways of getting a repeated event (so that you can do something in stages gradually over time) are `DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER` and CADisplayLink. But I think a timer is probably the simplest way to get started.

If you have a pre-existing sound that you're playing, a completely different solution is to apply a fadeout to it *before* you start playing it (and then just play it all at the same volume, because the sound *itself* fades out, do you see). AVFoundation gives you the tools to do that (e.g. `setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:toEndVolume:timeRange:`).