# How to change an iOS device volume programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

Is there a way to change the device volume programmatically? maybe using audio session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it is not possible to control the actual device volume (as this would also be a bit obtrusive) Controlling some media you're playing is another thing. You could however look into `MPVolumeView`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/index.html for displaying a view for setting the volume.

The question has also been discussed here:
[How to change device Volume on iOS - not music volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286744/how-to-change-device-volume-on-ios-not-music-volume)

Comment: Sorry I miss that discussion.

Comment: Look at this:

import MediaPlayer

    let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
    if let view = volumeView.subviews.first as? UISlider{
        view.value = 0.1 //---0 t0 1.0---

    }

Its working for me

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
import MediaPlayer

let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
if let view = volumeView.subviews.first as? UISlider{
    view.value = 0.1 //---0 t0 1.0---

}
```

Its working for me

Comment: This method is no longer working in iOS 11.4, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50740234/2610888

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this worked for me.

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = 1; // max volume
musicPlayer.volume = 0; // min volume (mute)
musicPlayer.volume = 0.0625; // 1 bar on the overlay volume display
```

Comment: That changes the relative volume of the media you're playing, but I'm pretty sure the actual volume ranges from 0 to the user's current volume setting. So if the user has the volume set to 1/2, your musicPlayer.volume setting of 1.0 would actually give you 1/2 volume.

Comment: that is deprecated from ios7

Answer (score 1):

Hacky but works (**Swift 3**):

```
func setVolumeTo(volume: Float) {
  (MPVolumeView().subviews.filter{NSStringFromClass($0.classForCoder) == "MPVolumeSlider"}.first as? UISlider)?.setValue(volume, animated: false)
}
```

Don't forget to `import MediaPlayer`

Comment: This actually works! Just make sure to do `import MediaPlayer` at the top.

Comment: I got a downvote so I assume it doesn't work on some newer iOS. If someone ends up testing this, let us know here in the comments which iOS you are running on. Thank you ;)