# iOS 9: How to change volume programmatically without showing system sound bar popup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpvolumeview

I have to change the volume on iPad and using this code:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0];
```

But this changing volume and showing system volume bar on iPad. **How to change the sound without showing the volume bar?**

I know, `setVolume:` is deprecated, and everybody says to use `MPVolumeView`. If this is the only way to solve my problem, then how to change the volume using `MPVolumeView`? I don't see any method in `MPVolumeView` that changes the sound. 
Should I use some another class together with `MPVolumeView`?

But it's preferable to use `MPMusicPlayerController`.

Thank you for advice!

Comment: You're not supposed to change the volume programmatically, that's the whole point of `setVolume:` being deprecated. You app could be rejected.

Comment: whats about SWIFTUI? How can we do it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681324/swiftui-change-sound-level

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`MPVolumeView` has a slider, and by changing the value of the slider, you can change the device volume. I wrote an `MPVolumeView` extension to easily access the slider:

```
extension MPVolumeView {
    var volumeSlider:UISlider {
        self.showsRouteButton = false
        self.showsVolumeSlider = false
        self.hidden = true
        var slider = UISlider()
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview.isKindOfClass(UISlider){
                slider = subview as! UISlider
                slider.continuous = false
                (subview as! UISlider).value = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
                return slider
            }
        }
        return slider
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this work? I am trying to use it without much success! I added a view and subclassed it to MPVolumeView but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Work for me! Thx!

Comment: this was super useful

Comment: I dont have problems on iOS 11.3. I do on iOS 11.4 @OttoBoy

Comment: @Karl-JohnChow Just tested and you are right. Before iOS 11.4 is working well, on iOS 11.4 it doesn't.

Comment: @Karl-JohnChow I asked on SO, waiting maybe someone could help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737943/how-to-change-volume-programmatically-on-ios-11-4

Comment: @Karl-JohnChow I added working solution on iOS 11.4 here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168497/ios-9-how-to-change-volume-programmatically-without-showing-system-sound-bar-po/50740234#50740234

Answer (score 77):

For 2018, working on iOS 11.4

You need to change `slider.value` after a small delay.

```
extension MPVolumeView {
  static func setVolume(_ volume: Float) {
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
    let slider = volumeView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.01) {
      slider?.value = volume
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
MPVolumeView.setVolume(0.5)
```

## [Objective-C version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737943/how-to-change-volume-programmatically-on-ios-11-4/50740074#50740074)

Comment: In my case it's working in iOS 11.4 only setting a much longer deadline (e.g., DispatchTime.now() + 0.5)

Comment: @AndreaGorrieri It still works with 0.01 delay without showing system sound bar. Seem like maybe you have another additional problem here. Anyway, upvoted your comment for someone else has same issue. Thanks!

Comment: This works for me, thanks. But each time the volume is increased, I get the following log:
_[] <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None_
Has anyone been able to get rid of that message?

Comment: @KerCodex As I know, this warning appears whenever `MPVolumeView` is initialized (from xib, storyboard or programmatically). Currently, seem like it still works good with this warning and no one has solution to avoid warning in this case.

Comment: @SimonPham I tried on iOS 12.0 and it works as expected. Make sure you run on real device, not simulator. If it still doesn't work, you can try to increase delay time as AndreaGorrieri comment above.

Comment: @trungduc maybe it's because I call the function when the app is in background. Does it need to be on foreground?
I use real device. I increased the delay to 0.5 but still doesn't work

Comment: @SimonPham Of course, you have to call it on foreground.

Comment: do you have any solution for my problem? I need to call it when the app comes to background.

Comment: @SimonPham Actually changing volume programmatically is updating an `UIKit` component which is `UISlider`. Your question will become how to update UI while app is in background. I think it's impossible.

Comment: @trungduc I'm unable to get this to work on iOS 12, the system HUD still shows for me! Could you post an exact code sample?

Comment: Perfect example!

Comment: This wasn't working for me (running iOS 12 and swift 4) and then I increased the deadline like @AndreaGorrieri did and it works fine :).

Comment: This is a great solution. What is the need to use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` in setting and getting the volume? I rewrote this extension without it and it still works.. unless I am missing something.

Comment: This code is flawed — it creates a brand new `MPVolumeView` UI object every time you set the volume. I assume the async wait is needed because it could take the system a while to initialize this new object. I recommend creating the `MPVolumeView` once at launch — then use it anytime without a wait and without wasting battery.

Comment: Working for iOS 13 and 13+ as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
extension UIViewController {
  func setVolumeStealthily(_ volume: Float) {
    guard let view = viewIfLoaded else {
      assertionFailure("The view must be loaded to set the volume with no UI")
      return
    }

    let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)

    guard let slider = volumeView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider else {
      assertionFailure("Unable to find the slider")
      return
    }

    volumeView.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(volumeView)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) { [weak slider, weak volumeView] in
      slider?.setValue(volume, animated: false)
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) { [weak volumeView] in
        volumeView?.removeFromSuperview()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
// set volume to 50%
viewController.setVolume(0.5)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution in Swift. It might be a shady one, so I'll let you know if Apple approved this when I publish. Meantime, this works just fine for me:

1. Define an MPVolumeView and an optional UISlider in your View Controller

   ```
   private let volumeView: MPVolumeView = MPVolumeView()
   private var volumeSlider: UISlider?
   ```
2. In the storyboard, define a view that's hidden from the user (height=0 should do the trick), and set an outlet for it (we'll call it *hiddenView* here). This step is only good if you want NOT to display the volume HUD when changing the volume (see note below):

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var hiddenView: UIView!
   ```
3. In viewDidLoad() or somewhere init-y that runs once, catch the UISlider that actually controls the volume into the optional UISlider from step (1):

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       ...

       hiddenView.addSubview(volumeView)
       for view in volumeView.subviews {
           if let vs = view as? UISlider {
               volumeSlider = vs
               break
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. When you want to set the volume in your code, just set volumeSlider?.value to be anywhere between 0.0 and 1.0, e.g. for increasing the volume:

   ```
   func someFunc() {
       if volumeSlider?.value < 0.99 {
           volumeSlider?.value += 0.01
       } else {
           volumeSlider?.value = 1.0
       }
   }
   ```

**Important note:**
This solution will **prevent the iPhone's Volume HUD from appearing** - either when you change the volume in your code, or when the user clicks the external volume buttons. If you do want to display the HUD, then skip all the hidden view stuff, and don't add the MPVolumeView as a subview at all. This will cause iOS to display the HUD when the volume changes.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5 / iOS 13**

Here is the most reliable way I have found to access the system volume level. This is based on other answers here but does not waste energy nor require an async wait.

During initialization (such as in `viewDidLoad`), create an off-screen `MPVolumeView`:

```
var hiddenSystemVolumeSlider: UISlider!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: -CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, y:0, width:0, height:0))
    view.addSubview(volumeView)
    hiddenSystemVolumeSlider = volumeView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider
}
```

Then use the hidden slider to get or set the system volume whenever you need it:

```
var systemVolume:Float {
    get {
        return hiddenSystemVolumeSlider.value
    }
    set {
        hiddenSystemVolumeSlider.value = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only method that I could get to work in 9/2023. Is this still the best method for setting the volume? Is there a way to not call up the system volume slider?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is any way to change the volume without flashing volume control. You should use `MPVolumeView` like this:

```
MPVolumeView* volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] init];

// Get the Volume Slider
UISlider* volumeViewSlider = nil;

for (UIView *view in [volumeView subviews]){
    if ([view.class.description isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]){
        volumeViewSlider = (UISlider*)view;
        break;
    }
}

// Fake the volume setting
[volumeViewSlider setValue:1.0f animated:YES];
[volumeViewSlider sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: This works for me on iOS8 but does NOT work on iOS9. Is there a iOS9 workaround?

Answer (score 3):

@udjat 's answer in **Swift 3**

```
extension MPVolumeView {
    var volumeSlider: UISlider? {
        showsRouteButton = false
        showsVolumeSlider = false
        isHidden = true
        for subview in subviews where subview is UISlider {
            let slider =  subview as! UISlider
            slider.isContinuous = false
            slider.value = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
            return slider
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Version: Swift 3 & Xcode 8.1**

```
extension MPVolumeView {
    var volumeSlider:UISlider { // hacking for changing volume by programing
        var slider = UISlider()
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview is UISlider {
                slider = subview as! UISlider
                slider.isContinuous = false
                (subview as! UISlider).value = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
                return slider
            }
        }
        return slider
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you supposed to use this?

Comment: Hi @JonathanPlackett, you can try like this:
`self.volumeSlider.value = 1 // get the max volume`
BTW, self means MPVolumeView instance. Hope for help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my volume control for my audio player app:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class UIVolumeSlider: UISlider {

    private let keyVolume = "outputVolume"
    
    func activate(){
        updatePositionForSystemVolume()
        
        guard let view = superview else { return }
        let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)
        volumeView.alpha = 0.000001
        view.addSubview(volumeView)
        
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyVolume, options: .new, context: nil)
        
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    
    func deactivate(){
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyVolume)
        removeTarget(self, action: nil, for: .valueChanged)
        superview?.subviews.first(where: {$0 is MPVolumeView})?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
    
    func updatePositionForSystemVolume(){
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        value = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
    }
    
    
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == keyVolume, let newVal = change?[.newKey] as? Float {
            setValue(newVal, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    
    @objc private func valueChanged(){
        guard let superview = superview else {return}
        guard let volumeView = superview.subviews.first(where: {$0 is MPVolumeView}) as? MPVolumeView else { return }
        guard let slider = volumeView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider else { return }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.01) {
            slider.value = self.value
        }
    }
}
```

How to connect:

1. Set UIVolumeSlider class in Identity Inspector on storyboard:

[image]

2. Connect instance to class:

```
@IBOutlet private var volumeSlider:UIVolumeSlider!
```

3. In **viewDidLoad** method:

```
volumeSlider.updatePositionForSystemVolume()
```

4. Activate and deactivate it in **didAppear** and **willDisappear**:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        volumeSlider.activate()
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        volumeSlider.deactivate()
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }
```

Comment: use viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear.

Comment: very bad - "outputVolume" string literal multiple times, UI merged with logic (so I can't for example take your code and use it with `AVPlayer` instead of `MediaPlayer`) and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Swift > 2.2, iOS > 8.0,

I didn't find any solution I was looking but I end up doing this as solution:

```
let volumeView = MPVolumeView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    view.addSubview(volumeView)
    volumeView.alpha = 0.00001
}

func changeSpeakerSliderPanelControls(volume: Float) {
    for subview in self.volumeView.subviews {

        if subview.description.rangeOfString("MPVolumeSlider") != nil {
             let slider = subview as! UISlider
             slider.value = volume

             break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use default UISlider with this code:

```
    import MediaPlayer

    class CusomViewCOntroller: UIViewController

    // could be IBOutlet
    var customSlider = UISlider()

    // in code
    var systemSlider =  UISlider()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

       let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
       if let view = volumeView.subviews.first as? UISlider{
          systemSlider = view
       }
    }
```

next in code just write

```
systemSlider.value = customSlide.value
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't want to have to have my call within a view controller so I built a different solution. You can just call it from anywhere like this:

`SystemVolumeController.shared.systemVolume = 0.5`

One thing to keep in mind with all the MPVolumeView solutions is while the MPVolumeView is on screen the little slider that appears at the side of the screen when a user presses the volume buttons on the side of the phone doesn't appear. For this reason I built into this solution a timer that removes the view after a few seconds.

Some of the solutions here suggest you need to set a delay before setting the volume. I haven't found that to be the case for me but your mileage may vary.

````
import MediaPlayer

final class SystemVolumeController {
    
    static let shared: SystemVolumeController = SystemVolumeController()
    
    private weak var volumeView: MPVolumeView?
        
    private var removeTimer: Timer?
    
    private func getVolumeView() -> MPVolumeView? {
        if let volumeView = volumeView {
            return volumeView
        }
        else {
            removeTimer?.invalidate()
            
            let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: -CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, y:0, width:0, height:0))
            guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first else {
                assertionFailure("No window to add the volume slider to")
                return nil
            }
            window.addSubview(volumeView)
            self.volumeView = volumeView
            
            removeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3,
                                               repeats: false,
                                               block: { _ in
                volumeView.removeFromSuperview()
            })
            
            return volumeView
        }
    }
        
    private var volumeSlider: UISlider? {
        getVolumeView()?.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider
    }
    
    var systemVolume: Float {
        get {
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
        }
        set {
            volumeSlider?.value = newValue
        }
    }
    
    private init() {}
    
}```
````