# iOS play sound file with constant volume, independent of user settings

Tags: ios, audio, volume

Is there any way in iOS to keep playing a sound file at a constant sound volume? So no matter if the user did set the ringtone of his phone to very low volume, I still want to play my audio file at the same volume as if the phone was set to loud. Kind of like what Siri does. She's also independent of every other sound-volume setting.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 9: How to change volume programmatically without showing system sound bar popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168497/ios-9-how-to-change-volume-programmatically-without-showing-system-sound-bar-po)

Comment: Everything you need is in AVAudioSession docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/

Comment: @NSDmitry I already had a look there... `outputVolume`, which sounded like it would work, is read only. The `MPVolumeView` hack... is ... well... a hack...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everybody wondering. `AVAudioPlayer` has a property `volume` that can be set higher than 1. So you would figure out what the current device volume is using `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume` and then adjust the AVAudioPlayer volume to compensate the difference.

Note that the sound quality is not going to improve ;)
So best thing is just to not do that ;)

Comment: That’s actually a nice idea. Do you have an equation for this? I’m trying simple `player.volume = desiredVolume / session.outputVolume` and it does some compensation, but it doesn’t seem to play at constant volume. It’s probably some exponential/logarithmic equation.

Comment: I found better one: `player.volume = pow(desiredVolume / session.outputVolume, 2)`. There’s no science behind this, I only verified this empirically using my ears. This achieves constant volume for any user settings. PS: Don’t forget to handle division by zero.