# Swift: how to set the iphone volume programmatically

Tags: iphone, swift, avaudioplayer, volume, mpvolumeview

I am trying to create an alarm app and I have noticed that apps like Sleep Cycle will set your volume to max right before the alarm goes off, even if you had the volume at very low.

I have tried using AVAudioPlayer and all I have seen with MPVolumeView is that the user must do it. 
Is there any way I can turn it up without the user having to do it?

Thank you for your help.

If I could please get the code in swift

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just need to import MediaPlayer. You can do as follow:

```
import MediaPlayer
```

And to set the volume to maximum

```
(MPVolumeView().subviews.filter{NSStringFromClass($0.classForCoder) == "MPVolumeSlider"}.first as? UISlider)?.setValue(1, animated: false)
```

Comment: THAT'S IT! Thank you

Comment: The best solution! Tnx!

Comment: I think this is risky and possible grounds for rejecting an app and at best it's an unstable solution. I can't think of any other way of doing it programmatically but be warned this probably violates terms.

Comment: this is not working in ios 11.4 please let me know if you have a different way

Comment: For iOS 11.4 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50740234/2610888