# How to set System volume programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am getting System volume from following code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
      addObserver:self
      selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
      name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
      object:nil];
 - (void) volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)  
 {
     float volume = [[[notification userInfo]
                     objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]
                     floatValue];

     // here volume is the .....
 }
```

but how to set system or devices volume from xcode (Objective C)

Comment: This for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859402/ios-change-device-volume . Hope you will find some helpful information.

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688123/how-to-set-app-volume-separately-from-system-volume-ios-device-volume-physical/36813028#36813028

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to programmatically set the system volume without calling private methods/using private APIs.

You would have to call `_commitVolumeChange` which is private API and will definitely get your app rejected.

Further reading [here](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/06/adjusting-iphone-master-volume.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you (if you can get access to AVPlayer object and want to change the volume of your playing Asset), I use such code for modifying volume in my AVPlayer while playing video.

```
- (void)setVolume:(CGFloat)volumeToSet forPlayer:(AVPlayer *)avPlayer {
    AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset *) [[avPlayer currentItem] asset];
    NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

    NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =    [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
        [audioInputParams setVolume:volumeToSet atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
        [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
    }
    AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    [audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

    [[avPlayer currentItem] setAudioMix:audioZeroMix];
}
```

More details about this solution here [Adjusting the volume of a playing AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268949/adjusting-the-volume-of-a-playing-avplayer)

If you would like to change device's volume look here, this is workaround and may broke in some iOS versions, but works now in iOS 7, iOS 8, iOS 9 (tested it).
[iOS 9: How to change volume programmatically without showing system sound bar popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168497/ios-9-how-to-change-volume-programmatically-without-showing-system-sound-bar-po)