# Change volume of MPMusicPlayerController without changing system volume

Tags: objective-c, ios10, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpvolumeview

My app has a feature to play system music player's music and it has it's own audio too. When music player's music is playing and app's audio will begin to play, I have to decrease the music player volume without affecting app's volume.

I am currently changing music player's volume with `MPVolumeView` as `MPMusicPlayerController` `volume` property is deprecated. But it is system volume which affects app's volume too though I have used `[avAudioPlayer setVolume:1.0]`, which is quite natural.

My question is, is there any way to change the music player's volume without affecting app's volume?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can only change device volume with `MPVolumeView`. If you want to change application volume, there is `AVAudioPlayer`. It has `volume` property, so you can change your volume that way.

Comment: I am already doing that. I am using `MPVolumeView` to change volume of `MPMusicPlayerController`. Is there any other way to do that? As changing system volume is affecting app's volume also.

Comment: You can't change music volume without changing app or device volume.

Comment: changing device volume is affecting app's `AVAudioPlayer` volume too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688123/how-to-set-app-volume-separately-from-system-volume-ios-device-volume-physical