# How to get/set iOS stream volume?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

In android, ways to get/set stream volume by using [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html):

```java
audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,musicVolume,0)
```

what are equivalents in iOS?

I managed to find [categories](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/audio_session_categories?language=objc) in `AVAudioSession`and [system volume](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616533-outputvolume?language=objc) But find no way to set/get specific category volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this apple documentation MPVolumeView - https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview.

Comment: I am looking for a way to get/set it directly without native UI, since I am using Unity here. But your answer provide some clues for me. Thanks

Comment: Check this link. They should help you get started. -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688123/how-to-set-app-volume-separately-from-system-volume-ios-device-volume-physical

Comment: @AlexWei I know this is an old one, but if you found a way to mimic what we can do in Android, could you post your code here or in a gist? Thanks for that.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT As far as I can recall, the problem was solved by using a different SDK. I didn't find a native way to do that in iOS at that time.