# How to change tvOS system volume

Tags: volume, tvos, mpvolumeview

On iOS [we can use MPVolumeView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307653/543875) to change the system volume but it's not available on tvOS.

Is there any API that allows us to change tvOS' system volume?

Comment: We're building a hardware controller that features a rotating wheel our users want to use to change volume on Apple TV

Answer (score 1):

The best I found was according to an apple dev. q&a [concerning master volumes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1016/_index.html) 
**Every device may not support master volume control or individual channel control** 
however you should be able to use coreAudio as supported in tvOS

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look into it and report back.

Comment: any insight into the solution?

Comment: Needed to move focus, but I'll come back to you and grant you the bounty soon!

Comment: It's expired I believe, right? via [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: I'll simply create a new bounty as soon as I go into it (probably next week).

Comment: Alright, thanks. I appreciate it. I do hope it helps, though.