# How to mute MPMoviePlayerController in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mpmoviewcontroller

I need to use MPMoviePlayerController in the application, but their is no such method to control volume. I found one solution in obj-c. but it didnt work in swift. Can anyone please help me?

```
    [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0]
```

Comment: just update your question with your whole player code that start value 1 and mute value 0

Comment: check this : https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624567-volume

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MPVolumeView? Just like here:
[iOS 9: How to change volume programmatically without showing system sound bar popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168497/ios-9-how-to-change-volume-programmatically-without-showing-system-sound-bar-po)
And sorry for not making a comment, my reputation doesn't allow me doing this.