# How to set system sound,also change by programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

In iPhone/iPad, how to programmatically set system sound? Also how to control system sound programmatically? I went through many web documents but couldn't find exact solution. Please any one help me out. Is it possible to access system configuration through app?

Comment: A slider control used to set the system audio output volume, and a button for choosing the audio output route.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change an iOS device volume programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049699/how-to-change-an-ios-device-volume-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

System/Device sounds cannot be set from the App. Custom sounds can be added inside the app and can be played for any of your App's activity. For your App's notifications, custom sounds can be used but that has to be set from the App itself.