# How to change ios volume in swift with help UISlider

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uislider, volume

I wrote the following code, but it doesn't change iOS System Volume, it only changes the sound from within the app.
`audioPlayer` is subclass of `AVAudioPlayer`

```
   @IBAction func sliderVol(sender: UISlider) {
        audioPlayer.volume = sender.value
    }
```

The UISlider has the sent event of value changed
How can I change iOS system volume with help `UISlider`?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286744/how-to-change-device-volume-on-ios-not-music-volume) can help

Comment: @Aladin This not fit because gave the error " 'volume' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MPVolumeView` class is designed to let you do exactly this. It's in `MediaPlayer` framework. So, add that to your app to make things build correctly.

You create it and make it visible the way you instantiate any other subclass of `UIView`, which you probably know by now.

You can provide your own frame and use this to change the system volume.

```
var wrapperView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(30, 200, 260, 20))
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
self.view.addSubview(wrapperView)

// 3
var volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: wrapperView.bounds)
wrapperView.addSubview(volumeView)
```

For more help you can look here [Controlling system volume using swift](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/volume-view-tutorial-ios8-swift)