# How to get the iPOD/iPHONE "Ringer and Alert"device volume from setting->sounds section

Tags: ios

I want to get the iPOD/iPHONE "Ringer and Alert" device volume from setting->sounds section. i am able to get the device volume but not the ringer and alert volume.

Please can someone help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
                                         name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
                                       object:nil];

- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary*dict=notification.userInfo;
    float newVolume =
    [[dict objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]floatValue];
    // newVolume is value that you need
}
```

Read further information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22129911/2071323) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218729/ios-7-mpmusicplayercontroller-volume-deprecated-how-to-change-device-volume-no/24993026#24993026).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried this code, which will give me device volume not the Ringer and Alert volume. If i keep both the volume different and run the code. will always give the device volume.