# Programmatically set 'audio volume balance’ on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-audio

I am wondering if it is possible to programmatically set L & R 'audio volume balance’ on iOS as in Settings>General>Accessibility.

This would not have to override the users global setting but achieve the same behaviour from within an app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change device Volume on iOS - not music volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286744/how-to-change-device-volume-on-ios-not-music-volume)

Comment: Thanks but volume balance is with respect to L & R (similar to panning but not exactly)

Comment: Which API are you using to play audio? Depending, there are ways to pan. p.s. is this about the iphone 7 top speaker?

Comment: In fact it is specifically related to the iPhone 7 - we want to only play from the bottom. Is there something different in the way the 7 behaves (compared to the other stereo phones)? I'm using AudioUnit within AVAudioSession.